Wildfly not picking logging handler update
I am using Wildfly 30.0.1.Final.
I have changed logging mechanism from periodic log handler to size rotating handler in standalone.xml file in configurations directory. It is picking the change when I start from bin/standalone.bat file but when I install the service and start the service, it is again creating service logging files with date at the end of the file names.
I have also removed console handler but it is still creating wildfly-stdout logging file. I have confirmed it has picked standalone.xml file from localhost:9990 wildfly console but it is still not working.
My new logging handlers in standalone.xml looks like:
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
           <size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
<formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
                        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <rotate-size value="100m"/> <!-- Set log file size limit -->
            <max-backup-index value="30"/> <!-- Keep logs for 30 days -->
           <append value="true"/>
               </size-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>


By service, do you mean the Windows service shipped in the WildFly, docs/contrib/scripts/service/service.bat ?
